# Get battery voltage and temperature from Ibeacon using Cordova-BLE Plugin

Tags: cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, eddystone

I trying to get battery voltage and temperature from Beacon device using Intel XDK with Cordova BLE Plugin https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central. When i scan my app its get only device ID and RSSI value. My deviceID look like MAC Address (D4:3A:72:47:A0:39). ble.scan() function works fine, but can't able to connect using ble.connect() function. I also tried the cordova eddystone plugin https://github.com/evothings/cordova-eddystone also. In this plugin, scan function also not working evothings.eddystone.startScan(foundBeacon, scanError). Anyone can explain how to proceed it further. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do the Beacon really give information about battery voltage and temperature? What bacon exactly?

Comment: Yes, the device name is "iBeacon" . I just tried in some playstore app (i.e., nRF Connect), it gets temperature and battery voltage also.

Answer (score 0):

The standard iBeacon format does not provide battery or temperature data.  Eddystone telemetry frames do so, and some beacon manufacturers provide proprietary extensions allowing getting this info.

To get these data programmatically, you need to first find the manufacturer documentation to see if it is using Eddystone or extensions to send these data.  If extensions, the plugins probably will not work.  If Eddystone, look for a plugin allowing you to access Eddystone telemetry.